# How to write an integration test in spring boot for MongoDB @Transnational

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, transactions

I have use @Transactional annotation with saving call (I am using MongoDB) and it works completely fine but I want to write the integration test for it. I have used the firebase authentication in application. Please can anyone tell me how I can write the integration test for it? this is the method for which I want to write a test.

```
@Override
@Transactional
public DatabaseWriteResponse<UserDetails> save(UserDetails userDetails) throws AuthorizationException {
    DatabaseWriteResponse<UserDetails> response = null;
    try {
        response = save(userDetails);
    } catch (UncategorizedMongoDbException | MongoCommandException e) {
        TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus().setRollbackOnly();
        response = new DatabaseWriteResponse<>();
        response.setStatus(STATUS.WRITE_CONFLICT);
        return response;
    }
    return response;
}
```

I have tried this

```
@Test
public void saveUserDetailsByTwoUserAtSameTime() throws InterruptedException {
    List<DatabaseWriteResponse.STATUS> ls = new ArrayList<DatabaseWriteResponse.STATUS>();
    Thread thread1 = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            DatabaseWriteResponse response = userDetailsStorageManager.save(userDetails);
            ls.add(response.getStatus());
        }
    };
    Thread thread2 = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            DatabaseWriteResponse response = userDetailsStorageManager.save(userDetails);
            ls.add(response.getStatus());
        }
    };

    thread1.start();
    thread2.start();

    thread1.join();
    thread2.join();
}
```

I have written a customUserSecurityContext class to mock users for testing.
when I call `DatabaseWriteResponse response = userDetailsStorageManager.save(userDetails);` without thread it is working but in this case I can't test transaction and when i call it from threads it gives me authentication failure error.

Comment: are you trying to write unit test for multithreaded scenario. Also, I do not see any mocks in your code. Please explain what is the intent of your test.

Comment: As you can see I have use transactions with save call, I want to write an integration test to check if the transaction if working or not. when I test it from the UI by login two users and make the save call at the same time, its working fine and but I want to know how to write an integration test for it.